# Game Development

Tags: java, android, eclipse, limit

Hi i'd like to develop a Dating Sim App for Android with eclipse.

The Game consists of Scenes.
Each Scene consists of one Background Picture (City), one Charakter Picture and one Balloon Image with text in it (Text which the Character says).
When i tap the Balloon, the next Scene will appear, the spoken text will change, maybe one of the pictures will change too.

It's a very simple game it just consists of .png Pictures and Text Strings.

This is my problem:
I assumed that every scene has to be an activity (each of my scenes has it's own layout.xml)
So i created now like 200 layouts, and just started to do the java classes for each activity (each class states, when a button is pressed, please go to the next layout file.)
It all worked pretty well until activity 25 or so appeared. When i tap it, the game crashes.
I tried to fix it with "finish" (please see code below) but it didn't help. Maybe i used it the wrong way?

I tried to bypass the activity that crashes (switched from Activity 25 to Activity 30 instead from 25 to 26) But it also crashes.

Questions 1:
Do i have to many Activites loaded? How can i fix it?

I really would like to continue with "Each Scene is one Activity" if possible, because it's the most easiest way to do it for now.

Question 2:
How would a professional Programmer do this?
Would he create a flash Animation for this and insert it as a view in ONE Activity?
Or just plain Java code?

Thank you very much in common.

```java
package com.irbstudios.zargoslovestories;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class game_p1_prestory_00001 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.game_p1_prestory_00001);
        TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
          Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
          "fonts/rosemary.ttf");
          tx.setTypeface(custom_font);
          Intent svc=new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
          startService(svc); //OR stopService(svc); 

}

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View view) {                                          //Relevant Part for StackOverflow Question:

        if(view.getId() == R.id.btn_prestory_00000) {                               //when the balloon is touched
            startActivity(new Intent(this, game_p1_prestory_00002.class));          //got to the next activity
            finish();                                                               //delete this activity out memory.
            }



      }
}
```

Comment: A professional would create one activity and have it dynamically load different layout.xml using `setContentView()`

Comment: You could make fragments which load their own layout and keep swapping out.

Comment: Flash is not supported in Android as its been discontinued. There's a deprecated plugin player around that kind of works in old versions of the stock browser, but you won't be able to insert a flash animation in a view. But Android has an excellent framework to build hardware-accelerated animations. See ObjectAnimator, it's pretty close to Flash Tweens.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following:

- Create an activity with a full screen `ViewPager`
- Create a `Fragment` that will be a "scene", but this fragment would be able to load **any of the layouts**. As a starting point, just convert one of your activities to a fragment, it's pretty straightforward.
- Create a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to display your fragments inside the `ViewPager`

This is a very compact structure, and it allows you to define very cool transitions (cube/3d/fadings/scrolls...) between scenes with very little effort (see `PageTransformers` when you have a working prototype)

After this is done, to change scenes you can do:

```
   mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1); // change to scene 1
```

Some Docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html